# Excel VBA - if cell is empty input something, else return error

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to create a database that represents a warehouse with named bays.  This will have functions to both Log In materials and to check them out when they are needed.

My excel workbook has a Log In sheet and seven sheets labelled Row A to Row G to represent the aisles in the warehouse.  Each aisle has five shelves and a number of bays.  This information is concatenated to give a unique Location.  I am currently struggling with asking VBA to check whether the Location a material is to be assigned to is empty or not, and if it is, then it should paste information copied from the Log In sheet.  Unfortunately, no matter what is in my sheet, the code just fills the ActiveCell with "TRUE" and brings up the error message that I've asked for if it isn't true.  I've tried IfEmpty as well, with the same result.

My code looks like this:

```
Sub LogIn()

Dim Row As String
Dim Location As String

' assign values to variables
    Worksheets("Log In").Activate
        Location = Cells(6, 3).Value
        Row = Cells(3, 3).Value

' copy new inputs to clipboard
    Sheets("Log In").Range("C8:C11").Copy

' find the correct location within the separate racking sheets
    Sheets("Row " & Row).Activate
    Selection = Cells.Find(What:=Location, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False).Activate
    Selection = Sheets("Log In").Cells(6, 3).Value
    Selection = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Activate

' check whether location is empty
     If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then

' paste new inputs onto racking sheet
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

' or return an error
        Else: MsgBox "The location you have selected is currently occupied"
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Selection` wrong. First I'll explain what is happening, then how to hopefully fix it.

When you write something like

```
Selection = "Hello"
```

It fills the selected cells with "Hello". Excel can't set `Selection` to "Hello", instead it sets the values of all selected cells to "Hello", i.e. it's the same as

```
Selection.Value = "Hello"
```

You are using `Selection = something.Activate` and I assume that means you want to select `something`. It sorta does that but not how you want.

`something.Activate` activates (and therefore selects) the cell or range `something`. It also returns the boolean value `True` (I don't know when it would return `False`, maybe someone else can help). So when the line `Selection = something.Activate` is executed, VBA first evaluates what is on the right hand side of `=` which returns `True` (and during that evaluating also selects `something`). Now it sets `Selection.Value` to `True`and because `something` was just selected, `something.Value` gets set to `True`.

---

Now the best thing you can do is to stop using `Selection` and `Activate`. If you need to use the `ActiveCell` as some sort of user input, set a Range to the ActiveCell at the beginning of the sub and use it when needed.

Instead of changing the `ActiveCell` all the time, use variables. Something like this:

```
Dim myCell as Range
'...
Set myCell = Sheets("Row " & Row).Cells.Find(.... 'You should rename Row because it's already a property of Range.
myCell.Value = Sheets("Log In").Cells(6, 3).Value
Set myCell = myCell.Offset(0, 2)

If myCell.Value = "" Then 
'...
```

Comment: That's really good to know.  To save time and rewriting, I've made it work simply by removing `Selection = `from in front of the `ActiveCell.Offset`